# Trigger android download manager Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, download

I'm trying to download files with a Cordova app, this is working fine for smaller files using the [File transfer plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer), but for bigger files I would like to trigger the android download manager. Is this possible(probably with a plugin)?

I need to be able to change the headers of the request, so the ['cordova plugin background download'](https://github.com/sgrebnov/cordova-plugin-background-download)
plugin didn't help me.

Comment: This is one plugin which matches your requirement and comparitively active - https://github.com/fastrde/cordova-plugin-fastrde-downloader

Comment: fork the plugin, add the header capability and send a PR so the original plugin can benefit of it.

Comment: @DavidWestern Any update on this?

Comment: @Ghandi, please read the edit

Comment: @MarkNi This is one plugin which matches your requirement and comparitively active - http://github.com/fastrde/cordova-plugin-fastrde-downloader

Answer (score 6):

The best way to go is to write your own plugin. Writing Cordova plugins is easy, and it is enough just to follow official doc. We done the same because also it was necessary to customize download process. It looks like a native call using this method, because it activate native DM so user can see progress, cancel it, pause etc.

And once you register your own plugin this is code that you can use to start with:

```
    import android.app.DownloadManager;
        import android.app.DownloadManager.Request;

        public class DownloadPlugin extends CordovaPlugin{

        private DownloadManager downloadManager;

        public DownloadPlugin() {
           downloadManager = (DownloadManager) webView.getContext()
                                                               .getSystemService(webView.getContext().DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args,
                               CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

          String downloadUrl = args.getString(0);
          startDownloadForUrl(String downloadUrl);

        }

        public void startDownloadForUrl(String downloadUrl){
                Request downloadRequest = new Request(downloadUrl);
                if (accessToken != null) { // we use oauth so this is example of changing download request
                    downloadRequest.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "
                            + accessToken);
                }
                downloadRequest
                .setDescription("description")
                .setDestinationInExternalFilesDir("folderName", "fileName");
                downloadManager.enqueue(downloadRequest);  
        }

       }
```

Comment: why not fork the plugin he mentions and send a PR to make it better?

Comment: 'cordova plugin background download' did not used DownloadManager(I checked they still don't use it, they use HttpURLConnection). And we wanted to use DownloadManager because it have a lot of features out of the box. Now there are a lot of plugins that were not there before, and lot of them are using DM eg. https://github.com/sgrebnov/cordova-plugin-background-download. For this one it make sense what you said. 'cordova plugin background download' is "official" Cordova plugin for download and they will for sure not change the way how it works for years.

Comment: In the question, the plugin called 'cordova plugin background download' links to https://github.com/sgrebnov/cordova-plugin-background-download, which uses the DM. That's the one I was referring to about sending a PR for adding headers support. The one that is a core plugin and doesn't use DM is the file-transfer plugin

Comment: It can be the way of course, as well, if someone prefer. Adding headers should be straightforward using linked plugin.

Answer (score 1):

This is one readymade [downloader plugin](https://github.com/fastrde/cordova-plugin-fastrde-downloader) which matches your requirement and comparitively active.

It also provides various options for downloading as mentioned in the [usage](https://github.com/fastrde/cordova-plugin-fastrde-downloader#usage) link

Answer (score 0):

This is another [downloadmanager plugin](https://github.com/vasani-arpit/cordova-plugin-downloadmanager) which shows a notification when the file is downloaded and is suitable for the original task.

Also I made a [fork](https://github.com/SlidEnergy/cordova-plugin-downloadmanager) and added a method to raise a notification if the file had already been downloaded before. This is necessary when the file is downloaded via the web api and you need to check the response from the server before saving the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the next plugin.

It works with Android and iPhone.

https://github.com/ogarzonm85/cordova-plugin-downloader.git